# Functions aren't printing properly, couts of each function are printed first and the returned values are printed last

Tags: c++, function, printing, return, cout

I have this c++ piece of code which I wrote in CodeBlocks:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double square(double arg) {
    cout<<"double ";
   return arg * arg;
}
int square(int arg) {
    cout<<"int ";
   return arg * arg;
}
int main(void) {
   cout << square(2) << " " << square(2.) << " " << square('A') << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

For some reason the print is:
`int double int 4 4 4225`
instead of:
`int 4 double 4 int 4225`

I tried compiling in Visual Studio Code's C++, but I still get `int double int 4 4 4225`. The code seems to print properly on online compilers.

Comment: You have to use C++17 which adds "ordering" with `operator <<`.

Comment: See [eval order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules) (19) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Prior C++17, evaluation order for operands of `operator <<` is unsequenced.

so, in

```
std::cout << " " << square(2.)
```

`square(2.)` might be evaluated (with its printing side-effect) before `std::cout << " "`.

Since C++17, new [rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules) has been added to have "expected" behavior:

> 19. In a shift operator expression E1 << E2 and E1 >> E2, every value computation and side effect of E1 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E2.